# How to continue video play while orientation change in android

Tags: android

I used videoview for playing a video in android default player. When I change its orientation, it starts playing from beginning.

How could I make it to continue from that point, where orientation changed ?

Comment: Did you try to indicate in the Manifest file that your Activity handles orientation change?

Answer (score 17):

Add:

```
<activity
    android:name="...your_activity..."
    android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"
/>
```

to the AndroidManifest file, to the Activity that handles video play back.

Comment: Ive tried this.but its UI fits for landscape well.But again video starts playing from beginning

Comment: Are you sure you are not missing the "orientation" attribute in configChanges?

Comment: i can able to use like this on manifest   android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|keyboardHidden" I cant able to use screeSize

Answer (score 4):

When you change the orientation the OS destroys your activity, and recreates it.

You can save the actual progress of the video in `onSaveInstanceState()` and get the saved data in `onRestoreInstanceState()` from the `Bundle`, after that you can start the playing with either the progress data, or from the beginning if there was no data saved.

Comment: @Adam L. Mónos, It is good. But video is buffering while changing the orientation. It shouldn't happen. Can you please tell me how to overcome this?

Comment: If you are loading the video in an `AsyncTask` then you have to cancel the loading manually in `onPause()` and start/restart it in `onResume()`. Though I don't really see the problem with this behaviour. If you need more sophisticated help, you should open a new question.